# Why did the king lend Gimil-Ninurta his chariot?

Tags: akkadian-language

In ["The Poor Man of Nippur,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poor_Man_of_Nippur?wprov=sfla1) Gimil-Ninurta seeks the first part of his revenge upon the mayor of Nippur, who has insulted and mistreated him, by borrowing a chariot and the clothing of a wealthy noble from the king, promising to pay him a mina of gold in compensation.

However, it's not clear to me why the king would lend anything to a man from another city who was so impoverished that he needed to sell the clothing off his back to buy a goat. Why would he believe that such a person could ever gather a mina of gold, and was not simply planning to rob him? Indeed, the story seems to call attention to the king's lack of concern:

> The ruler did not ask him: "What is your desire, that you want to
> parade a whole day in one chariot?" They gave him a new chariot, as
> appropriate to noblemen.

What motivated the king to extend this kind of credit to Gimil-Ninurta?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing absolutely nothing of the story aside from the linked Wikipedia entry which [Lord Jim somewhat inappropriately added most of the intro to](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Poor_Man_of_Nippur&oldid=187873434), I'd say the most obvious answer within the story itself is this bit

> In his city, Nippur, he lived, working hard, but
> Had not the silver befitting his class,
> Had not the gold befitting people [of his stature]...

Apparently Gimil-Ninurta is a noble whose branch of the family has fallen on hard times. At the same time, he's apparently still recognized as a noble which—at the time although not explicitly stated in the story—would've made him a relative of the gods in some way and easily could've mean he was physically or culturally distinct, as different groups (Sumerians, Akkadians, Babylonians, Assyrians, &c.) rose to power and subjugated other nearby peoples.

It's a longstanding trope and truism that the upper class protect and extend greater privileges to their own than to the common herd. If you could ask the king himself, there might be something about Hospitality or the virtue of aiding the Stranger, but it's always been standard that a certain class of people get extra consideration on those issues even when they're down on their luck.

Comment: "as appropriate to noblemen" in the OP's quote also supports this.